# Probability of a biased die

Tags: probability

A die with 1 painted on three sides, 2 painted on two sides, and 3 painted on one side is rolled 15 times. What is the probability that we will get eight 1's, six 2's and a 3 on the last roll?

Comment: Any thoughts?  This looks like a straight forward homework problem, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting with what you know.

$P(x=1)=\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$

$P(x=2)=\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$

$P(x=3)=\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{6}$

The probability of 8 1's = $P(x=1)^8$

The probability of 6 2's = $P(x=2)^6$

The probability of 1 3's = $P(x=3)^1$

The probability of 8 1's and 6 2's and one 3 = $P(x=1)^8P(x=2)^6P(x=3)$

You need to assign eight 1's and six 2's to the first 14 rolls, but you can arrange these in any order. How many possible arrangements are there? You calculate this as [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations) of 14 items taken 6 at a time, denoted as $\binom{14}{6}$.

So the final answer would be $P=\binom{14}{6}P(x=1)^8P(x=2)^6P(x=3)$.

Comment: Why take $\binom{14}{6}$ instead of  $\binom{14}{8}$? Thanks

Comment: They are the same thing. $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. Let $m=n-k \implies k=n-m$. Then $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!(n-n+m)!}=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!(m)!}$.